# What is launcher.ebproductions.android.launcher?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, launcher

I've just removed GO Launcher and now when I click the home button I get offered a choice of two different Launcher `com.android.launcher` and `launcher.ebproductions.android.launcher`

What is the ebproductions one? Do I need it?

Can I just remove it?

Comment: [Eugene](http://eb-productions.proboards.com/index.cgi) is a fairly well-known ROM cooker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an app in the Market with the ID "com.ebproductions.android.launcher" that is [Gingerbread Launcher free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ebproductions.android.launcher).

This appears to be a slightly modified version of the AOSP stock Gingerbread launcher that someone's made available for devices that don't come with the stock launcher installed.

Comment: I may have installed it when I had my GalaxyS and it came back when I synced my account.

Answer (score 2):

Following the package name you provided, the app you are talking about is called [Gingerbread Launcher free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ebproductions.android.launcher) from the developer Eugene373.

You must have installed this launcher before install Go launcher. Go launcher was your default launcher and after you removed it the system is asking you to choose between the Android's launcher and this one.

If you don't need it you can remove it.